# How to set the height of a component in html to a parcentage of a parent component?

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, styles, height

I'm working on a web application and we are developing it in Java and jsf. I made a component for selecting data which is used inside other components (like wizards, modal panels and so on). Thing is, I need to set the height of the component to a percentage of the wizards height it's inside. I tried with javascript, and the problem I have is that the window.onload command doesn't work when I have it inside of my component. For now I'm just trying to alert() the height of the parent component, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <![CDATA[

    window.onload = setHeight;

    function setHeight()
    {
        var element = document.getElementById("#{rich:clientId('mainWizardDiv')}");
        var h = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("height");
        alert(h);
    }
    ]]>
</script>
```

Do you have any other suggestion how this could be done, some way i could go around using onload, or any other idea. Thanks.

Comment: window is the global scope, not a DOM object.
Try tu use an eventListener on a DOM object:
document.body.addEventListener('load', setHeight);

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work"? Please try to be more accurate : is the function `setHeight` called at the `onload`? Does `h`have any value? Is your script in the body or the head?

Comment: `h` has a value, and the setHeight() function does work. Problem is that it isn't called when I get to the page with my component.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to get percentage height (google for height percentage for reasons). Get absole height in pixels, count it in Javascript (don!t forget to round it) and load the result to element what you want to (adding 'px' string just to be sure). That was always working for me.

**EDIT:** (after posting comment)

**Maybe, I can see mistake. You are assigning function which is not defined. First, you have to define function and THEN use it**

Comment: The way in which I get it isn't the issue, my main problem is how to set it when the my component is shown.

Comment: Maybe, I can see mistake. You are assigning function which is not defined. First, you have to define function and THEN use it.

Comment: My code works, just not in the way i need it to work, the function gets called when i press the "reload" button in the browser. But it doesn't get called when i navigate to the page that contains my component from within the page.

Comment: "Maybe, I can see mistake. You are assigning function which is not defined. First, you have to define function and THEN use it." NO: when parsing, js first define all functions and then execute the code. There is not problem in this order.

Answer (score 0):

Bad use of CDATA:
CDATA should be commented to avoid the js syntax error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //<![CDATA[

            window.addEventListener('load', setHeight);

            function setHeight()
            {
                var element = document.getElementById("div1");
                var h = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("height");
                alert(h);
            }
            //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='height:200px; width:200px;' id='div1'>

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note that this is only applicable if the document is served as `application/xhtml+xml`, which would in turn cause severe problems in MSIE. It's more likely that the document is *actually* served as `text/html` and thus OP's initial usage of CDATA is correct. See also among others https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML

Comment: Commented CDATA may be used either in text/html and application/xhtml, and in this case it seem to be the problem. In my opinion, CDATA is a old/poor practice that create more problem than it resolve.

Comment: Old/poor practice? Sorry, but I have now more the impression that you have no utter idea what you're talking about :)

Comment: Personally I preffer to write full external libraries and include them into the html.
That avoid a lot of problems: code insertion, mix 3-4 languages in the same file and help to maintain a clean code.

CDATA is a patch to "solve" problems like:
- old web browsers that do not accept JS
- code incertion

PD: I speak about using CDATA to includeJS, not about the generic use in XML which is useful.

Comment: Completely true, but that has in turn completely nothing to do with CDATA at its own.